# BST time complexity: Is there any difference between float value and int value?

Tags: data-structures, tree, big-o, binary-search-tree, time-complexity

Given a BST of float numbers and a BST for int numbers. I'm just wondering that is there any  time complexity difference of insertion, deletion, etc. between different data type based BST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of a binary search tree is usually expressed in terms of the number of comparisons made. For example, saying the runtime for an insertion is O(log n) means that only O(log n) comparisons are made. If the comparisons themselves take some extra amount of time (for example, if you're comparing strings), then the runtime might change to reflect that.

Comparing `float`s does take a bit more time than comparing `int`s, but it's still a constant amount of work (that is, O(1)). Therefore, the runtime should still be O(log n), though it might be a bit slower due to the extra hardware involved in doing a floating-point comparison.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I'm asking, thanks. But why compare floats take  more time than compare int? sizeof(float) is equal to sizeof(int) which is 4.

Comment: @DoReMi- Depending on the hardware, there might be a special floating-point unit responsible for doing operations on floating-point values. The generated code might have to issue commands to the FPU to load the values, compare them, then send them back to the ALU for further processing. It's the same reason why operations on `double`s can be much slower than operations on `long long`s, though on most systems `double` and `long long` are 64 bits. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

No. The time complexity is derived from the structure and characteristics of the algorithm itself (like how many nested loops, or how much recursion), not the type of data it operates on.

Search, insert and delete are in a BST are O(log n) on average, O(n)  in the worst case.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) for more on BSTs.